# ¿Cómo direccionar siempre a la URL correcta?

Tags: php, url

Tengo una regla `.htaccess` que permite visualizar los datos a pesar de que el usuario manipule o modifique las categorías.

Ejemplo si el usuario visita la siguiente dirección: `example.com/categoria/otracategoria/mi-url/`

Y llega modificarla de la siguiente forma: `example.com/categoria/cat/plus/mi-url/`

Los datos se mostraran de igual forma, el detalle de ese producto se mostrara sin errores, excepto si modifica esto `mi-url` ahí si, el sistema muestra el siguiente mensaje: *el producto no existe.*

No se, si sea correcto dejarlo tal cual, no me parece que sea inseguro, en SEO, solo se indexara las `URL`, que están correctamente en el sistema, entonces crearía yo de que no existe problema en ello.

Pero por otra parte, creo yo, que se vería mejor que se visualicen los datos en la `URL` correcta.

Entonces obteniendo la *URL* de los registros de la columna `url`

```
id    url
1   cat/1/producto/mi-url/
```

Mediante una variable llamada `$urlcorrecta` y mediante cierta condición si esa variable no coincide con la ruta web **UR** direccionar a la `url` verdadera/correcta.

Por ejemplo si esta es la `url` correcta, `example.com/cat/1/producto/mi-url/` y si se manipula la **URL** así: `example.com/cat/otro/1/mi-url/` y que mediante PHP al comprobarse se direccione a la verdadera **URL**: `example.com/cat/1/producto/mi-url/`

¿Cómo puedo implementar esta comprobación?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes comprobar si la url es la que esperas en `php` y en caso de no serlo redirigirle a la correcta con un `301`.

```
$url_correcta = "aqui la url esperada para el producto";
if($midominioweb."/".$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] != $url_correcta){
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: ".$url_correcta);
    header("Connection: close");
    exit;
}
```